# Linux Script confusion

Tags: linux, bash, shell

what is the "eval" doing in this script? What does this evaluate to?

```
#!/bin/bash    
n=1    
for i `eval echo {1..$1}`    
do    
   n=$((n * i))     
done
```

Comment: the backticks evaluate the expression; `eval` evaluates the curly braces which expand from 1 to $1 (argument of your function). I think that just `for i in \`echo {1..$1}\`` would do it.

Comment: Using `eval` is generally a bad thing. consider using `seq` instead: `for i in \`seq 1 $1\`; do echo $i; done`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eval executes the shell command that it finds in its arguments. You need to do this because the `..` operator requires its arguments to be literal numbers, not variables.

```
eval echo {1..$1}
```

first substitutes the value of `$1` into the argument as part of normal variable substitution. If the argument to the script was 5, this becomes:

```
eval echo {1..5}
```

Then `eval` executes that command, so it executes:

```
echo 1 2 3 4 5
```

Since this is all inside backticks, the output of the `echo` is substituted into the `for` line, so it becomes:

```
for i in 1 2 3 4 5
```

Comment: Thank you, that make a lot of sense!

Answer (score 2):

To avoid confusion and the usage of `eval` you can use [c-style for-loop](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/ccmd/c_for):

```
for ((i=1; i<=$1; i++))
```

Comment: C language always makes more sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

The `eval echo {1..$1}` generates a list of all numbers from `1` to the first argument. You then loop through all those values and multiply them to `n`, generating `n!`.

The `{a..b}` syntax generates a list of all the numbers from `a` to `b`, inclusive. You have to call `eval` because the `..` syntax requires numbers, not variables - putting the `eval` allows variable substitution before running the command.

I also suspect that you wanted to write `` for i in `eval echo {1..$1}` ``, not `` for i `eval echo {1..$1}` ``, as the latter generates a syntax error.

Comment: Yes, I did forget the "in". Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: Re: "`eval` does variable substitution before it runs the command": This is true in general, but in this case there is no parameter substitution for it to do. The `$1` is replaced with `5` before `eval` is even invoked.